# Data query to timeline chart

Tags: javascript

I need a help.
I would like to see the last 24 hours in the timeline Chart. This is the formatted datetime DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS.

This is the data source: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H602ZpDfwl044qjDyIDfscOWoaSqLzjsvb3TuZXEK6c/edit#gid=0

I'm getting en error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Does anyone have any idea to solve this?

```
    <html>
  <head>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization',
       'version':'1','packages':['timeline']}]}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {


  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H602ZpDfwl044qjDyIDfscOWoaSqLzjsvb3TuZXEK6c/edit#gid=0');
      var nowone = getNowDate();
      query.setQuery("select A,B,C where B >= datetime '"+nowone+"' ");
      query.send(handleQueryResponse);

      }

function getNowDate(){

var d=new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);

var year = d.getFullYear();  
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var day = d.getDate();
var hour = d.getHours();
var minute = d.getMinutes();
var second = d.getSeconds();
var microsecond = d.getDate();

if (month.toString().length == 1) {
    month = '0' + month;
}

if (day.toString().length == 1) {
    day = '0' + day;
}

if (hour.toString().length == 1) {
    hour = '0' + hour;
}

if (minute.toString().length == 1) {
    minute = '0' + minute;
}

if (second.toString().length == 1) {
    second = '0' + second;
}

//while(microsecond.toString().length < 3) {
//    microsecond = '0' + microsecond;
//}

var dateString = year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second';
return dateString;
}


function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
    }

    var data = response.getDataTable();      

  var options = {
    timeline: { singleColor: '#8d8' },
  };
 var container = document.getElementById('example5.2');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  chart.draw(data, options);
  setTimeout(drawChart, 5000);
}
</script>
 </head>
  <body>
<div id="example5.2" style="height: 500px;"></div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Badly formatted question and your answer is really broad, start by commenting part by part of your code till you get to line with the error, you can't fix that line, then place it here. You're error has nothing to do with GAS/Google visualiztion, is a Javascript error.

Comment: I just edited as suggested. Do you have any idea how  to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is purely a JS issue.  You have an extra quote in JS that doesn't belong.  When you set your time, it should be:

```
var dateString = year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second;
```

Instead of

```
var dateString = year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second';
```

If you remove the extraneous quote, your error will go away.

Comment: You're welcome, sometimes and extra pair of eyes is all it takes.  It might help for your to use an editor that syntactically colorizes the text, that will help show errors if the color is not what you expect.  Also, please 'accept' the answer.